# hook on javascript "document.addEventListener"

Tags: javascript, events

in my html, I've got an event binding as below:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
```

Now that I'd like to hook on the `keydown` event, i.e., when `keydown` happens, call another function and  trigger the `onKeyDown` manually.

the `document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);` is already there(upstream) and I don't want to change it. so to sum up:

```
`keydown` -> `do something` -> `onKeyDown`
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to execute the `onKeyDown()` on a specific key press ?

Comment: [No parenthesis!](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2)

Comment: @Bergi thanks I've edited the question to fix that. @ubercooluk, yep, the document.addEventListener is already there I don't want to change it(upstream), I want to add hook during `keydown`: `keydown`-> do something -> onKeydown.

Comment: Do you mean [dispatch an event manually](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `onKeyDown` method could be accessed, you can remove it from event listeners and reattach a modified version:

```
function myKeyDown() {
    // your logic
    onKeyDone.apply(this, arguments);
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', myKeyDown);
document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
```